# Do I need a premium edition of Azure Active Directory when I integrate it with Keycloak?

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

My client has Keycloak installed to broker users from AWS Cognito. **I need this Keycloak to also broker users from Azure Active Directory.**

The client has an OFFICE 365 APPS edition of AAD.

**Do I need a premium edition of Azure Active Directory in order to achieve this?**

I found this in [pricing page of AAD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)
I'm not sure if it's related to my use case.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you are paying attention to 3rd party MFA partner integration. Do you just want to set AD FS as Brokered Identity Provider in Keycloak?

Comment: I don't pay attention to MFA too much, the more important seems "3rd party identity governance partners integration" for me. This question is not related to ADFS, but Azure Active Directory.

Comment: I think you do but have reached out to that team to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we don't have an official Azure AD App gallery solution for this. So you might have to use a Non-Gallery application template if you would like to use SAML here. And you need a Premium P1 or P2 license to create non-gallery apps.

(Note that neither I nor my product team contacts at Azure are experts at Keycloak.)